# Code Efficiency + Time Cost Clarification for Palindromic String Decompositions

Tags: python, string, recursion, time-complexity

**Question 1**:

For the problem of generating all the palindromic decompositions of a given string, the author provides the following solution:

```
def palindromic_decompositions(input):
  def directed_palindrome_partitioning(offset, partial_partition):
    if offset == len(input):
      result.append(list(partial_partition))
      return 

    for i in range(offset + 1, len(input) + 1):
      prefix = input[offset:i]
      if prefix == prefix[::-1]:
        directed_palindrome_partitioning(i, partial_partition + [prefix])

  result = []
  directed_palindrome_partitioning(0, [])
  return result
```

On line 4, you'll see `partial_partition` wrapped in a `list()` function, which effectively just makes a copy of `partial partition` and appends it to the result.

However, since we are never mutating partial_partition, I think this is a wasteful duplication of `partial_partition`. Each function call just reassigns partial_partition to the argument. Is my understanding correct here?

I ran this code, and a copy of the code without the `list()` on the following input case: `(palindromic_decompositions('0204451881')` and got the same output.

**Question 2:**
The time cost provided of the problem is n x (2^n), but there is no provided explanation. I understand the `n` part is because of the `list(partial_partition)` -> can someone explain where the (`2^n`) comes from?

Answer (score 0):

For Q1: `list()` is redundant because `partial_partition + [prefix]` also makes a copy. Otherwise, without it `result` would be filled with pointers to the same underlying object.